# Pagination not working Properly after particular count

Tags: php, html

I am going to create a pagination then

```php
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

total I have 240 rows then:

```php
if($num_row>5){
    $count=0;
    $index=1;
    while($count < $num_row && $index < 5){ ?>
        <button id="<?php echo $count; ?>" class="index_b"><?php echo $index; ?></button>
    <?php
        $count = $count + 5;
        $index++;
    }
}
```

I want first 1 2 3 4 5 then next button so I tried

```php
<div class="next_index_b">
<?php if($num_row > 50){?>
    <button class="next_membd_index_button" name="50" ><img src="images/arrow.png" /></button>
<?php } ?>
```

Now my issue is after 4th pagination number, no number is working.

Comment: You need to help us help you first, by giving us a _proper_ problem description - “not working” is not one. Please go read [ask].

Comment: First of all you should provide more code, about your querys. You should have two query one for count (all elements) and second for get pagination elements (limit, offset) Also you should have good if statement in your html code to handle numbers of pages and how they looks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `mysqli_num_rows()`! Ideally, you should pull ONLY the data that you're looking for, and then run 2 separate queries. One to fetch the full count, and one to fetch the items per page:

```
$db = new PDO(...);

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$offset = ($page-1) * 50;
$count = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")->fetchColumn();

$trans = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT :offset, 50");
$trans->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$trans->execute();


while ($row = $trans->fetchRow()) {
   // echo data
}

//Add footer here. Use $page variable and $count to determine how many pages are available.
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
    while($count < $num_row && $index < 5){ ?>
```

This condition means that *when $index equals 5, the loop is stopped*

Therefore, the button with 5 will never be shown.

Try using *less or equal than* instead of *less than*

```php
if($num_row>5){
    $count=0;
    $index=1;
    while($count < $num_row && $index <= 5){ ?>
        <button id="<?php echo $count; ?>" class="index_b"><?php echo $index; ?></button>
    <?php
        $count = $count + 5;
        $index++;
    }
}
```

Or even better, switch to @FrankerZ's solution